# I want to make app in flutter in which I play music and my music will be listened to by other user during calls

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make an app in Flutter in which I play music and my music will be listened to by other users during calls. How to give music as input to the microphone so that users on call in WhatsApp or any other calls can listen to the music that I played.